# Which distro has glibc 2.2.5 installed default?

Tags: glibc, distributions

I want to know which 64 bit distro has glibc 2.2.5 installed default. I found that debian 3 woody has that version.But I cannot download it. Please suggest how to do and where can I download ISO.

Comment: If you’re looking for 64-bit *x86*, Debian 3 wasn’t available for that archirecture so it won’t be of any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are trying to do but you can create a docker, possibly an alpine docker and install it there.

http://lfs.sourceforge.net/view/cvs/chapter06/glibc.html

Comment: RoboTamer , I cannot find glibc.2.2.5-2.patch file. When I install without it, it says "GNU library is not currently not available for this platform". So ,what should I do?

Comment: Now, I patch alpine linux with the patch file.But I still cannot run ./configure. It shows that gcc version is bad and make version is bad. So, I think I should install old version gcc. But I cannot also run configure file of gcc-3.2.3 because it shows errors. Please help me.